# ASP.NET: Is it possible to call async Task in Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, task, global-asax

I need to call some async operations on my DB in Global.asax.
for example in Application_AuthenticateRequest I need to Authenticate user against DB
Is it possible with async Tasks?

Comment: Why do you want to authenticate asynchronously? Shouldn't that be done synchronously?

Comment: because on many user requests sychronouse calls to DB forse others requers to be put in queue - it increase responce time.
look at [Asynchronous Database Calls With Task-based Asynchronous Programming Model (TAP) in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: We managed to increase our throughput by handling the AuthenticateRequest asynchronously. No need for the thread to be blocked by the network.

Answer (score 35):

There's an easier way to do this now:

```
    public MvcApplication()
    {
        var wrapper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(DoAsyncWork);
        this.AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync(wrapper.BeginEventHandler, wrapper.EndEventHandler);
    }

    private async Task DoAsyncWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var ctx = app.Context;

        ...
        await doSomethingAsync();
    }
```

With this approach, you define a method using the async keyword and wrap that method using the 'EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper' class to generate BeginEventHandler and EndEventHandler methods to pass into the AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync call.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to using the new C# keyword async and await, but we can still using APM pattern to use async operations in Global.asax because it implemented IHttpAsyncHandler interface. Here is a small code to demo async, here I use a WebRequst as example, in your case please use database operation instead.

```
    public Global()
    {
        this.AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync(BeginGetAsyncData, EndGetAsyncData);
    }

    IAsyncResult BeginGetAsyncData(Object src, EventArgs args, AsyncCallback cb, Object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BeginGetAsyncData: thread #" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        return request.BeginGetResponse(cb, request); // call database async operation like SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader()
    }

    void EndGetAsyncData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EndGetAsyncData: thread #" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        WebRequest requst = (WebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        System.Net.WebResponse response = requst.EndGetResponse(ar); // call database async operation like SqlCommand.EndExecuteReader()

        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!
I've found :)
[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/373479/Writing-asynchronous-HTTP-Module-in-ASP-NET-4-5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/373479/Writing-asynchronous-HTTP-Module-in-ASP-NET-4-5)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the async version of the AuthenticateRequest yourself. Using the following code:

```
public MvcApplication()
{
    // Contrary to popular belief, this is called multiple times, one for each 'pipeline' created to handle a request.
    // Wire up the async authenticate request handler.
    AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync(BeginAuthenticateRequest, EndAuthenticateRequest, null);
}
```

The issue is then, how to implement `BeginAuthenticateRequest` and `EndAuthenticateRequest` using the new async/await features of C#. First, let's get our async version of AuthenticateRequest out of the way:

```
private async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Yay, let's do async stuff!
    await ...
}
```

What we need to do next is come up with an implementation of BeginAuthenticateRequest and EndAuthenticateRequest. I followed [a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/06/27/10179452.aspx), but derived my own implementation:

```
private IAsyncResult BeginAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    Task task = AuthenticateRequestAsync(sender, args);
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(state);

    task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null) tcs.TrySetException(task.Exception.InnerExceptions);
        else if (task.IsCanceled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else tcs.TrySetResult(true);

        if (callback != null) callback(tcs.Task);
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can read the entire linked article to see how it works, but basically `IAsyncResult` is implemented by Task, so all you have to do is call the callback when done.

The last bit is dead easy:

```
private void EndAuthenticateRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // Nothing to do here.   
}
```