# How can i make Recursion Asynchronous using Async and Await Keyword?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

i am getting multi-level dynamic menus from database. Currently i have called it successfully but i want to make it async. 
here is my code;

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var menus = Uow.Menus.GetAll()
        .Select(m => new ParentMenuViewModel()
        {
            MenuId = m.MenuId,
            Name = m.Name,
            ParentId = m.ParentId
        })
        .ToList<ParentMenuViewModel>();
    ViewBag.Menus = CreateVM(0, menus);
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}

public IEnumerable<ParentMenuViewModel> CreateVM(int parentid, List<ParentMenuViewModel> list)
{
    return list.Where(m=> m.ParentId==parentid)
        .Select(m=> new ParentMenuViewModel()
        {
            MenuId = m.MenuId,
            Name = m.Name,
            ParentId = m.ParentId,
            ChildMenus = CreateVM(m.MenuId, list)
        });
}
```

So, **how can i make this asynchronous using async and await keywords?**

Notice that, it loops until the children are loaded completely; 
**Is it even a good practice to make it async (the above code)?**

Comment: There is no point in making it async unless you have an actual async operation inside (which you don't)

Comment: so, if i mark it as async, this will have no positive feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `async` action filters are not available (yet); see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482338/async-action-filter-in-mvc-4). You can [vote here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9582) for the MVC team to add this capability.

Once MVC supports `async` action filters, you could use, e.g., `GetAllAsync`. The recursive part does not require any `async` functionality because it's not I/O-bound.

Comment: what about making the `CreateVM` method async?

Comment: `CreateVM` would not benefit from being `async`; see my edit.