# Asynchronous method is not returning in an MVC authorization filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have one test app where code similar to the following is working but similar code appears to be failing in another app:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var user = GetUser().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private async Task<User> GetUser()
{
    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var request = new UserSearchRequest
        {
            DomainName = "my-corp-domain\my-user-id"
        };

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/users/search", request);
    var users = (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>());
    return users.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

In the problem app, PostAsJsonAsync gets called but never returns.  Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?

Comment: There is [no reliable way to run async methods from an ASP.NET MVC action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024286).

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer:** Executing an asynchronous method inside a synchronous method often leads to deadlocks and performance issues. A fully asynchronous call path, or even a fully synchronous path, is preferred. If you absolutely must block on async methods, read on.

I've had similar cases where HttpClient requests never return, and the answer was usually deadlock. @Eser provided a link to another question that describes the deadlock process well. To summarize it, the call to `GetResult()` has blocked the thread. At the same time, `PostAsJsonAsync` is waiting for that same thread to unlock so it can finish processing, thus creating deadlock.

[An async/await example that causes a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock)

One possibility is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This tells `PostAsJsonAsync` that it can finish processing on a different context, rather than waiting for the original context to unlock. The `GetUser()` function would then look like this:

```
private async Task<User> GetUser()
{
    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var request = new UserSearchRequest
    {
        DomainName = "my-corp-domain\my-user-id"
    };

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/users/search", request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var users = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return users.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Another solution that I have used in the past is to wrap the synchronous execution inside `Task.Run`. This pushes the start of the async method into a different context, so the two methods won't try to block on the same one. The `AuthorizeCore` method would then look like this:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var user = Task.Run(() => GetUser()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

For more information on this method, see [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)

I emphasize again that neither is a perfect solution. By performing "sync over async" operations, you lose all benefits of asynchronous functionality while introducing a higher chance of deadlocks and potentially worse performance. I encourage using async all the way up whenever possible. When it's not, sticking with the "old" synchronous methods is not the worst option.

Comment: No, there is no reliable solution for running async code in a MVC action filter, as I described in the comments on the question. Playing around and trying to force it like you’ve done is going to result in issues.

Comment: I agree that there is no reliable way to run async code inside any synchronous method. I am not suggesting that "sync over async" is desirable in any way. My answer specifically addresses the scenario that an asynchronous method is not returning when called from a synchronous method.

Comment: Of course there are reliable ways - you just have to cough up a thread (Task) and then you lose all the benefits of async.

Comment: @Benj The problem is that your answer is teaching someone how to do async over sync, which is unreliable. You should just remove the answer, as it's not applicable here.

Comment: @bommelding You should not be launching your own threads in ASP.NET applications.

Comment: @bommelding No, this is not about performance. Async often runs *slower* than the equivalent synchronous code. Even if it were to run faster, that does you no good if it causes your service to go down due to deadlocks. And creating your own threads should not be done in ASP.NET either - you know that any unhandled exception in a thread you created yourself will crash the whole worker process?