# Detect session expiration inside asp.net mvc action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to detect session timeout inside mvc action method. I know that I can use Authorize attribute to detect it. But I don't want to use it at this moment.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Check()
{
    return View();
}
```

Is there any way to achive this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are now ActionFilter for async MVC methods:
[Async action filter in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482338/async-action-filter-in-mvc-4)

Try to authorize inside the action or call a authorize method inside async actions.