# How to Post/Get and not wait for the response (Async like Ajax) in asp net

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working with c# mvc 5 and I have a url which writes a log.
I call it in ajax in all my pages via javascript:

```
$.ajax({ url: log?page=index&userid=15, async: true });
```

Now I'm willing to log more critical data, so, for safety matters I need to remove this javascript from my pages, and instead, put it in every controller and every action of my projects.

There is a way to do this asyn in asp net mvc 5?
What I want is something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // I want a method that makes a post/get to some url, but don't block
    // the rest of the code. I don't need any return from the post
    // It would be nice to be a Post, but a Get would do the trick
    PostOrGetAsync("log?page=index&userid=15");
    return view();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a way to do this async in asp net mvc 5? What I want is something like this:

Yes.  However, your url in ajax `log?page=index&userid=15` does not appear to be a remote server so you can call it directly.

```
public async ActionResult Index()
{
  // I want a method that makes a post/get to some url, but don't block
  // the rest of the code. I don't need any return from the post
  // It would be nice to be a Post, but a Get would do the trick
  var controller = new LogController();
  await controller.Log("index", 15);
  return view();
}
```

This really isn't maintainable.  To make it global requires a little bit of work. You can use an [ActionFilter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) to globally log all calls.

```
public class LogActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
    Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
  }

  public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    Log("OnResultExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);       
  }

  public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
    Log("OnResultExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);       
  }


  private void Log(string methodName, RouteData routeData)
  {
    var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
    var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
    var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", 
      methodName, 
      controllerName, 
      actionName);

    Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
  }
}
```

You can either apply the Log to specific actions/controllers:

```
[LogActionFilter()]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return view();
}
```

or [all controllers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  // Register global filter
  GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());
  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
}
```

However, [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) does not currently support [async action filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482338/async-action-filter-in-mvc-4), but I don't think you need it anyway.

> I need some information that is inside the method. Like, when the user is creating a new registry.

```
[LogActionFilter()]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  SomeSharedLogic();

  return view();
}
```

Extension Method

```
public static ControllerExtensions()
{
  public static void SomeSharedLogic(this ControllerBase controller)
  {
    controller.TempData["ShareLogicValue"] = "WhateveR";
  }
}
```

Update the log method

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
  var sharedLogic = filterContext.Controller.TempData["ShareLogicValue"]
    as String;

  var logName = "OnActionExecuted";

  if (sharedLogic != null)
  {
    logName += ":" + sharedLogic;
  }

  Log(logName, filterContext.RouteData);       
}
```

Comment: I liked the Idea of user filters, but the problem is that I need some information that is inside the method. Like, when the user is creating a new registry, I log the user Id and the Id of the registry. Someone told me to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. Is this reliable? Like, imagine if I have 2 thousands of concurrent users. Will it handle?

Comment: ASP.Net can seriously easily handle 2,000 concurrent users on even crappy hardware.  If you have dependency on something that may happen, then checkout my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. What impacts could ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem cause? If I fire it 2000 times in a given time, should it bottleneck the system?

Comment: [Just read this](http://madskristensen.net/post/dont-use-the-threadpool-in-aspnet) synopsis: Don’t use the ThreadPool in ASP.NET.